# Return an empty array of char*

Tags: c, arrays, string

If I want to return an empty `char*`, I can do this

```
char* Fun1(void) {
 return "";
}
```

Now imagine the same problem with `char**`, I want to return an empty array of `char*`.

Is there a shorter way to write this without using a temporary variable ?

```
char** Fun2(void) {
 char* temp[1] = {""}; 
 return temp;
 // return {""}; // syntax error !
}
```

The goal is to hide the fact that the string can be a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Your `Func2` will result in undefined behavior, as you return a pointer to a local variable, which is not valid after the functions returns.

Comment: Besides the fact that you are returning a pointer to a local variable, which is not allowed, the array you are attempting to return is not actually empty (it contains an empty string). I don't understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: You say, "I want to return an empty array", but your code actually returns a (pointer to a) non-empty array, with 1 element, which is an empty string. I think first you have to decide what "empty" actually means to you. Once you've done that, you might make changes elsewhere in the code that make this question irrelevant.

Comment: Dude you clearly understood what I meant...

Comment: @John: I understand what you asked for, but I am not certain that what you asked for is wise :-) If you write code that takes an array that could have different lengths in different cases, then almost always you can make sure that code works with an empty array (that is, an array of length 0). Once the code works with an array of length 0, it will work with a null pointer, and this part of your program gets easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a temporary variable, as it will be out of scope on return. If you have multiple functions that return the same empty array, they can return pointers to the same 'empty array'.

```
char* EmptyArray[1] = {""}; 

char** Fun2(void) 
{
  return EmptyArray;
}
```

Also, this makes it easy to detect if the function specifically returned emptiness, by comparing pointers:-

```
char **arr =  Fun2(); 

if (arr == EmptyArray)
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent to what you did with the string literal would be something like this:

```
char const* const* Fun2(void) {
    static char const* const tmp[] = {""};
    return tmp;
}
```

But as I said in a comment to the question, you might need to re-think what "empty" means.

You also need to consider what you're going to do if there are cases where the return *isn't* empty. If the caller is supposed to free the returned pointer, then returning pointers to string literals and/or static arrays is out.

Comment: This seems way too complicated for what I want to do + it uses a temp variable. I would like to do this in one line.

Comment: I think you've underestimated how complicated memory management is in C. Anyway, the difference between strings and arrays in C is that string literals last for as long as the program runs, whereas C99 array literals only last as long as the expression they're used in, so they're not suitable to return from a function (and C89 doesn't have array literals at all). I don't think that what you want is possible.

Comment: @JohnPoe, why does it matter how many lines you use? You are using the wrong language if you want one line solutions.

Comment: I am the one asking questions here. Please be more constructive.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is not a good idea to return pointers from functions that have just been allocated. The problem is that the user then has to free that memory, and so you are forcing them to use the same memory management function as you are.

With that in mind, you want to allocate 2 bits of memory here: one for the pointer to a character and another for the character itself.

```
char** p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
*p = malloc(sizeof(**p));
**p = '\0';
return p;
```

And then remember the user then has to do:

```
free(*p);
free(p);
```

But I will say again, what you are doing is not good programming. You are better off writing functions that accept a null pointer.

Comment: Then for example everytime I printf something I would have to check if it is NULL ?

Comment: Returning pointers to things that haven't been `malloc`'d (and don't need to be) is idiomatic C programming. Think of the C strings functions - `strchr`, `strcpy`, etc... etc...

Comment: @John: Mat is suggesting that the `char**` is null. Why are you passing a `char**` to printf, and why would it matter that it is null when you do?

Comment: @Roddy, in both those cases the pointer returned is already in the string. Look at some examples that could create new strings... `sprintf`, `strcat` etc. They all require a previously allocated string to be given as the destination.

Comment: @Mat - yes, but my point is that mallocing stuff is a red herring. There's no need for it based on the question as given.

Comment: @Roddy, it's either that, or globals. I went with this because there was no `const` in the original question, which means they could be modified, which rules out globals.

Comment: @Mat, yeah - But I suspect the lack of const is not by design ;-)

Comment: @Roddy, I agree completely. But I also think that either way is completely the wrong approach, returning null is always better.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just return null, because null is empty pointer?

Comment: I have other parts of code that use Fun1 and Fun2, and that don't behave well with NULL value. So I would like to hide this error handling inside Fun1 and Fun2.

Answer (score 0):

the `{""}` only can be used to initial the variable at its definition. but not as an expression, that is, you can't use it like

```
char* temp[1];
temp = {""}; // invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

The first case is fine, a string literal such as `""` is safe to return from a function. For the second case, where you need an array of length 1 that contains a pointer to an empty string, you could do some trickery:

```
char ** array_empty_if_null(const char **array)
{
  static char *empty[] = { "" };

  return (array == NULL || array[0] == NULL) ? empty : array;
}
```

I think this matches your description of what you need.